# cannot retrieve data from 2 tables getting no result

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have 2 tables:
competition_winners where I am storing people who won competition and table competition where I am storing info about actual competition.

So I am retrieving winners and competition's end date. But the query responsible for date doesn't return anything. I am using Opencart so performing query in model. Here is its code.

```
public function getWinnersByDate($date) {
                $qr = "SELECT  competition_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners";
//$fcid = $qr->row['competition_id'];
        $query = "SELECT cometition_id,end_date FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition WHERE competition_id = '" .$qr->row['competition_id'] . "'"; 


        return $query->row;
```

Query works fine in PhpMyadmin. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running this in two queries You should be using `JOIN` (search about SQL `JOIN` on google).

```
public function getWinnersByDate($date) {
    $qr = $this->db->query("
        SELECT cw.competition_id, c.end_date 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "competition_winners cw
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "competition c ON c.competition_id = cw.competition_id
    "); 

     return $query->rows;
}
```

I do not know Your DB structure, but the query above has no sense in it's current state - I believe You want to add some `WHERE` clause using the provided `$date` argument and that You want to select more information from `competition_winners` table, so please, either do it Yourself or provide us with more details on Your problem.